# How to use Stokes' theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, multiple-integral, stokes-theorem

$\int_{K}\left(x^{2}+y z\right) d x+\left(y^{2}+x z\right) d y+\left(z^{2}-x y\right) d z$
where K is a closed curve, oriented positive, consisting of an arc defined by the parametric equation $x=a\cos t, y=a\sin t, z=\frac{1}{2\pi}t$ and segment $BA,A=(a,0,0),B=(a,0,1)$

I drew this K-curve for the parameter a = 2 to see what area we would integrate over.

[image: Curve K for a = 2]

That is, looking from above, it will be a circle of radius:
$$
S=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x^{2}+y^{2}=a^{2}\right\}
$$
In polar coordinate system
$$
\begin{aligned}
&0 \leqslant r \leqslant a \\
&0 \leqslant \vartheta \leqslant 2 \pi
\end{aligned}
$$

So I use Stokes' theorem because the assumptions are satisfied (see below).
Stokes’ theorem:

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a regular area and let $\sigma: D \rightarrow S \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a regular oriented surface with the edge of $\partial S$ being a piecewise smooth curve. Suppose that the surface $S$ is oriented according to its parameterization, that is, in such a way that according to the right-handed screw rule, the circulation around the curve determines the return of the vector normal to the surface. Let $G \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be an open set such that $G \supset S \cup \partial S$. Suppose that the function $f=(P, Q, R): G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is a function of the class $C^{(1)}$ in $G$. Then:

$$\int_{\partial S} P d x+Q d y+R d z=\iint_{S}\left(\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}\right) d y d z+\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}\right) d z d x+\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) d x d y$$

Auxiliary calculation:

$$
\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}=-x\,\,  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}=x\quad \,\,\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}=y\,\, \frac{\partial R}{\partial x}=-y\,\,  \frac{\partial R}{\partial x}=z\quad \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=z
$$

Then

$$
\int_K{\underset{P}{\underbrace{\left( x^2+yz \right) }}dx+\underset{Q}{\underbrace{\left( y^2+xz \right) }}dy+\underset{R}{\underbrace{\left( z^2-xy \right) }}dz}=\iint_S{-2x\,\,dydz}+2y\,\,dxdz\,\, +\,\,0 \cdot dxdy = \ldots \star (?)
$$

**Question:**

How to calculate this double integral ($\star$) ?

Did I make good use of Stokes' theorem?

Is there a faster way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note $S$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but your disk $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. There won't be a nice easy surface $S$ to work with here. It will be much simpler to compute the line integral directly on the two parameterized curves, without using Stokes' theorem.

Comment: @NiceJJ It is irrelevant that the projection of $K$ on the $XY$ plane is a circumference. In order to apply Stoke's theorem, $K$ must be the border of $S$.

Comment: S is not correct, my lecturer draw example S https://i.imgur.com/gvscKVt.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply Stokes' theorem,
$$\int_{K}\left(x^{2}+y z\right) d x+\left(y^{2}+x z\right) d y+\left(z^{2}-x y\right) d z=\iint_{S}  (-2x,2y,0)\cdot d\mathbf{S}$$
a correct example of $S$ such that $\partial S=K$ is the piecewise smooth oriented surface composed by
$$S_1=\{(a\cos(t),a\sin(t),\frac{st}{2\pi}, t\in [0,2\pi], s\in [0,1]\}$$ inward-oriented

$\hskip1in$ [image]

and the base disc $S_2=\{(x,y,0): x^2+y^2\leq a^2\}$ upward-oriented.

Then we find
\begin{align}\iint_{S_1} (-2x,2y,0)\cdot d\mathbf{S} &=\int_{s=0}^{1}\int_{t=0}^{2\pi} (-2a\cos(t),2a\sin(t),0)\cdot (-a\cos(t) \frac{t}{2\pi},-a\sin(t) \frac{t}{2\pi},0)\,dtds\\
&=\frac{a^2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}t(\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t))\,dt=0
\end{align}
and
$$\iint_{S_2}  (-2x,2y,0)\cdot d\mathbf{S} =\iint_{S_2}  (-2x,2y,0)\cdot (0,0,1)\, dS=0.$$
Hence, as $S=S_1\cup S_2$,
$$\iint_S (-2x,2y,0)\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\iint_{S_1}  (-2x,2y,0)\cdot d\mathbf{S}+\iint_{S_2}  (-2x,2y,0)\cdot d\mathbf{S}=0.$$

The same result can be obtained by direct computation of the line integral,
\begin{align}\int_{K}\left(x^{2}+y z\right) d x+\left(y^{2}+x z\right) d y+\left(z^{2}-x y\right) d z&=\int_{K}-2xy\, d z\\
&=-\frac{2a^2}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(t)\sin(t)\,dt+ \int_{1}^{0}0\,dt=0
\end{align}
where we noted that the vector field $(x^2+yz,y^2+xz,z^2+xy)$ is conservative with potential function $$U=\frac{1}{3}(x^3+y^3+z^3)+xyz.$$